# What causes external lower leg to visibly pulse?

Tags: blood-circulation, venous-system, arteries-artery

I wonder what causes the lower leg(fibula side) to pulse visibly for few minutes after exercising/walking etc. If the pulse is synchronised with the hearth rate, is it more likely to be a vein or an artery pulsating?

Comment: Veins do not really pulse, except when they "take" the pulse from nearby arteries. So, it's likely an artery pulsating. I'm not sure if this needs to "mean" anything (especially when there is no pain or other symptoms); it can be just normal.

Comment: Being able to see pulsing isn't unusual, and it's always an artery, never a vein. As Jan said, veins don't pulse (barring the presence of a shunt).